# How to generate new hourly timestamps of future in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I am writing this code to create a current timestamp:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This gives the following output:

```
'2020-07-02 01:00:00'
```

I want to generate all 24 hours of timestamp for a particular day, something like:

```
'2020-07-02 00:00:00'
'2020-07-02 01:00:00'
'2020-07-02 02:00:00'
'2020-07-02 03:00:00'
'2020-07-02 04:00:00'
'2020-07-02 05:00:00'
'2020-07-02 06:00:00'
.
.
.
'2020-07-02 22:00:00'
'2020-07-02 23:00:00'
```

One idea I have in mind, is to copy the date 24 times and create a string like `00:00:00` and then use some logic to increment it by one until `23:00:00` and then concatenate dates and these strings and then convert it into datetime object.

However, this seems like a lot of work if I want to do if its for 10 days that is 240 hours and 10 different dates in future.

Is there a logic that you can suggest to achieve future timestamps for all 24 hours (no minutes, no seconds) for however many days I require?

Something like:

```
number_of days = input('How many days timestamps do you need?')

my_timestamp_function(number_of_days):

   some_logic_using_the_number_of_days

   return pd.Series(output)
```

Thank you,
Viphawee

Comment: Check this, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Comment: @Sushant This one's really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

```
def generate_datetimes(date_from_str='2020-01-01', days=3):
   date_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
   for hour in range(24*days):
       yield date_from + datetime.timedelta(hours=hour)

for date in generate_datetime():
    print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

and you will get

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-01-01 01:00:00
2020-01-01 02:00:00
...
2020-01-03 22:00:00
2020-01-03 23:00:00
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Thanks for a timely response. If only I could upvote your answer, I will however, accept it as a solution in a couple of minutes. Thanks a lot.